# Google docs 3.0 java API upload file is not working properly

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I just downloaded newsest doc list api, and have a try. My code as below:

```java
DocsService client = new DocsService("testappv3");
client.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
File file = new File("c:/test.txt");
URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/defaults/private/full/");
String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
DocumentEntry newDocument = new DocumentEntry();
newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test"));
//newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaFileSource(file, mimeType));
newDocument.setFile(file, mimeType);
newDocument = client.insert(url, newDocument);
```

the error is below:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Not Found</H1>
<H2>Error 404</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI is incorrect:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/defaults/private/full/
```

Should be

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/
```

(with no s)

Comment: fine, it works, but if I add this `newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test"));` will got an error `com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: An unknown error has occurred.
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceException</code><internalReason>An unknown error has occurred.</internalReason></error></errors>`. Does this means I cannot give a new name for my document?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question for this.